# 2D FFT using 1D FFT on 1D vector

Tags: fft

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333454/2d-fft-using-1d-fft) i can apply 1DFFT on each row and then each column of a 2D vector.

If i have a 1D vector i can view it as a 2D using cells like this `v[rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex]`

My FFT1D algorithm is padding 0's to a vector until the next power of 2 position.

So if i am using it in this case on my 1D vector viewed as 2D, will it not add 0's where it is not supposed to, in between values, thus messing my result of the FFT2D?

Answer (score 1):

The actual algorithm (I am quoting from the post you referenced in your question) is:

1. 1D FFT on each row (real to complex)
2. 1D FFT on each column **resulting from** (1) (complex to complex)

The zero-padding might cause problems only if you modify the original 2D matrix while you are working on it, which doesn’t appear to be necessary.