# Using fft on 2d array flattened to 1d

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to understand the difference between applying fft.fft on a 1d array vs applying fft.fft2 on the same array reshaped to 2d.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

b = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])

a1 = fft.fft(a)

b1 = fft.fft2(b)
```

The output for a1 and b1 are different but I'm trying to understand how and why that would be so.

Comment: A 2D FFT is not mathematically the same as a 1D FFT of the flattened 2D data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11333566/253056

Comment: Just compare the [equation for the 1D DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) to that [for the  2D DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Multidimensional_DFT). You'll see they're different things. You can build the latter from the former, but not by flattening the array.

Comment: Do a preliminary research. See [Multidimensional DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Multidimensional_DFT).